# I can't change the color of the button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:gray;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin:1px;
}
body{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Jquery Project</title>
      <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.css">
      </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to Connect Four!</h1>
        <p>The object of this game is to connect four of your chips in a row!</p>
        <p id="inp">:it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your blue chip.</p>

  <table class="t">
    <thead >
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>
    <thead class="c2">
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>
    <thead>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead><br>



  </table>
      </div>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

```js
$(".circle").on("click",function(){
  $(this).css("background-color","red")
})
```

I am trying to make a game which is like a Tetris. Now I'm having trouble changing the color of the button.
I have to use JQuery.
However, I can't change the color of the button even when I click. I checked all syntax and it seems there's no problem with this coding for me. 
How can I make the color of buttons changed with JQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: It works my side: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/qBOKGmM

Comment: sorry I forgot to put CDN of JQuery.

Comment: If jQuery was not included, you should have been receiving an error regarding `$` not being defined in the console. Those errors are key to diagnosing and debugging; be sure to look for and include those errors (as text) when posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty much sure that you forgot to include jQuery.
Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the beginning of your document.
Here is your code:

```js
$(".circle").on("click",function(){
  $(this).css("background-color","red")
})
```

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:gray;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--Include jQuery!-->
<table class="t">
  <thead >
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
  </thead>
</table>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/qBOKGmM

Comment: Leaving out jQuery is really a "problem that was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers" and therefore should be closed as such. Even if not the case, there are many, many duplicates on Stack Overflow of this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I accidentally placed the can at the body, but when I moved it to head, it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Add jquery script bottom of the content**

1. Because of jquery script can't read dom before rendering the dom.
2. And also add working jquery CDN link inside the header tag. In the below, I have mentioned working jquery link.
3. Remember this, attach all the scripts below jquery script tag.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

```css
.circle{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:gray;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="t">
    <thead>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    <button class="circle" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </thead>
</table>


<script>
    $(".circle").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red")
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have updated my solution with a description.